# Why is `/` not allowed in regex pattern after `#`?

Tags: ruby, regex, literals

`x` option can be used to format a regex to make it more readable and introduce comments. So I tried:

```
my_pattern = / #dummy pattern to match everything
  .*  #/ <-- offending character
  /x
```

and I get an error:

```
main.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
```

What does this mean? I thought everything after `#` is ignored.

Comment: Are the comments in your regex literal what you literally have, or are they added only in this question? If it is the latter, then it is very confusing. Do not write explanations as comments, write it as text.

Comment: I had  `#TODO ^ or /` in my real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

Ruby interpreter saw

```
my_pattern = /whatever/ <-- offending character
/x
```

And that is not a valid Ruby code.

Comments are no special place, if you want literal `/` anywhere inside regex pattern, you need to escape `\/` them.

```
my_pattern = / .* #\/ <-- offending character /x
```

The other way, as Uri Agassi suggested, is using an alternative to wrapping the regex with `/` by using the `%r{}` form:

```
pattern = %r{ .* #/ <-- offending character }x
```

Then you watch out for literal `}`.

#### Long explanation

Try typing in interactive Ruby shell (`irb`):

```
irb(main):001:0> my_pattern = / #dummy_pattern to match everything
```

Ruby waits for more code, as expected.

```
irb(main):002:0/ .*  #/ <-- offending character
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Program crashed.

Notice, that the program didn't even get to the `/x` line, so **Ruby did not know that `#` is for comments**. It matched `/` - end of regex pattern (with literal `#`s as part of the regex) and then found

```
 <-- offending character
```

what is not valid Ruby code.

Ruby interpreter reads the same from either `.rb` file or `irb`.

If you need to have `/` inside your comment, escape it for the first pass of the ruby interpreter, ie,

```
irb(main):003:0> my_pattern = / #dummy_patter to match everything
irb(main):004:0/ .*  #\/ <-- offending character
irb(main):005:0/ /x
=> / #dummy_patter to match everything
.*  #\/ <-- offending character
/x
```

works as expected and matches everything (except for new lines of course):

```
irb(main):006:0> my_pattern.match("match me!")
=> #<MatchData "match me!">
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments): *"...the octothorpe (#) character introduces a comment until the end of the line"*

Comment: @Stefan: Only in code. But not inside a `String` literal, for example, nor in a `Regexp` literal. In a `String` or `Regexp` literal, it's just a character.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that quote is from the "Free-Spacing Mode and Comments" section in the `Regexp` documentation.

Comment: You could use an alternative to wrapping the regex with `/` by using the `%r{}` form: `pattern = %r{ .* #/ <-- offending character }x`

Comment: ...or `Regexp.new(' .* #/ <-- offending character ', Regexp::EXTENDED)
 => / .* #\/ <-- offending character /x`.

Comment: @Stefan: Uh, sorry, I missed that. Then it's definitely a bug, either in the docs or the parser.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, why a bug? Keep in mind that's only for the `/x` option.

Comment: @Cary: "until the end of the line" for me means "until the end of the line", not "until the end of the line or a `Regexp` delimiter". Changing the behavior would probably be complicated since AFAIK right now the parsers treat `Regexp` literals as black boxes and leave the parsing to the `Regexp` engine. So, clarifying the docs seems the more sensible option.